# Hibernate: Método get() devuelve una lista vacía

Tags: hibernate

Tengo la siguiente entidad "ProfesorEntity" el cual contiene un numero de legajo, un nombre, una direccion (la cual también es una entidad llamada "DireccionEntity") y una lista de materias (que también son una entidad llamada "MateriaEntity"):

```
@Entity

@Table(name="profesor")

public class ProfesorEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int numeroLegajo;
private String nombre;
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="direccion")
private DireccionEntity direccion;
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="Materia_Profesor", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="profesor")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="materia")})
private List<MateriaEntity> materias;
```

Luego tengo una clase "ProfesorDAO" en el cual tengo un método que se llama findByPk donde quiero que me devuelva el profesor con su direccion y sus correspondientes materias:

```
public Profesor findByPk(int numeroLegajo) 

{
    Session s = sf.openSession();
    ProfesorEntity pe = (ProfesorEntity) s.get(ProfesorEntity.class, numeroLegajo);

    if(pe!=null)
    {
        Profesor p = pe.toNegocio();
        s.close();
        return p;
    }
    else
    {
        s.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

El problema justamente es que el método "get" de Session sólo me carga los datos del profesor y la dirección, pero no me carga la lista de MateriasEntity con sus correspondientes materias, simplemente la deja vacía. Esto lo pude corroborar usando el debug.
Cual sería la manera más simple de que un método me devuelva el profesor con toda su información más la información de las tablas que tiene asociadas (En este caso direccion y materias)?

NOTA: El método "toNegocio" solo transforma de un "ProfesorEntity" a "Profesor", no le den importancia.

Edit: Acá pongo una foto de las tablas para que vean los datos cargados:
[image]

Comment: Solo para estar seguros... ¿has comprobado -accediendo directamente a la BD- que en la tabla de "Materias_Profesor" hay registros que referencian al profesor, y que las materias de dicha tabla existen en la tabla "Materia"?

Comment: Ahí edite mi consulta para que se vean las tablas cargadas. Sí, están todas las correspondientes tablas cargadas. Por eso me parece extraño que no levante nada. La única forma que encontre de que me llene la lista de materias es usando una sentencia HQL y el metodo "query.list()" pero me devuelve una lista de Object[] y yo necesito que sea de MateriaEntity

Answer (score 1):

No puedo garantizar que sea éste todo el problema (no tengo un entorno de desarrollo a mano), pero un fallo importante es que estás mezclando JPA e Hibernate.

- JPA: Es un API estándar de Java para ORM (*Object Relational Mapper*). Java sólo proporciona un API, y puedes seleccionar entre implementaciones de distintos proveedores.
- Hibernate: Es un ORM desarrollado por Red Hat. Aunque en principio es independiente de JPA y se puede usar por separado, también hay una capa "puente" que permite usarlo como una implementación de JPA.

El problema es que tus anotaciones son JPA (package `javax.persistence.`) pero luego usas las clases Hibernate (`org.hibernate`) para hacer las consultas. Eso no es bueno, ya que Hibernate sencillamente debe estar ignorando las anotaciones JPA al hacer la consulta.

La solución es ser consistente y usar uno u otro. Para hacer la prueba, supongo que lo más sencillo sería configurar un `javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit` (el equivalente a `SessionFactory` en JPA), crear un `EntityManager` (el equivalente a un `Session`) y de él hacer el `find()`.

De hecho, en general se recomienda que si usas JPA no uses **ninguna** anotación o clase de la implementación que vayas a usar, para mantener la portabilidad al máximo.

[Aquí hay documentación de como configurar JPA para que use Hibernate como implementación](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Ejemplo_sencillo_de_JPA_con_Java_SE). Por supuesto, si te es más sencillo, otra opción es quitar las anotaciones JPA, reemplazarlas por las propias de Hibernate y usar Hibernate directamente, sin la capa JPA.

Comment: Entiendo, de hecho eso explicaría por qué cuando hice funciones de guardado o eliminación y usé solo JPA todo funcionó correctamente. El problema es cuando quiero hacer métodos de recuperación, como es en este caso. La única forma que me enseñaron es utilizando el método get o list o load (según cada caso). Y si por mi fuera, haría lo que me decís, pero tengo que aprender de la manera que me enseñaron si o si (tengo un examen en una semana).
Así que mi problema se resumiría en: Como hago una recuperación de varios registros sin modificar las anotaciones que tengo en mis entidades?

Comment: Pues usando JPA. Configurar, si no lo está ya -fichero `persistence.xml`-, crear `EntityManagerFactory`, crear `EntityManager`, hacer `find`...) Aunque cambian los nombres, la estructura general es bastante similar (`find()` en vez de `get()`, etc.) En la documentación que enlacé explica los detalles bastante bien.

Comment: Es decir, no hay forma posible de, sin modificar las anotaciones, recuperar registros usando hibernate?

Comment: No. Si usas Hibernate directamente, solo hará caso a las anotaciones que reconoce. Pero si ya tienes el código para guardar y eliminar entidades a través de JPA, lo que te queda debería ser trivial. Ya deberías tener configurado el `persistence-unit`, y tener el código para obtener un `EntityManager`. Lo único que necesitarías sería hacer el `find()`.

Comment: Bueno, finalmente el problema se solucionó rediseñando la base de datos (estaba muy mal armada). Muchas gracias por la ayuda